# Rails InvalidURIError on redirect_to  with a valid url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, url, redirect

I am getting the `ERROR URI::InvalidURIError: bad URI(is not URI?)` on doing redirect_to.  below the full error mgs

```
[2011-12-05 16:17:10] ERROR URI::InvalidURIError: bad URI(is not URI?): http://0.0.0.0:3000/list/#/items/offered/list/80-21614629999999,13-0468673/15/0?Filters={}
/home/ramesh/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/uri/generic.rb:746:in `rescue in merge'
/home/ramesh/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/uri/generic.rb:743:in `merge'
/home/ramesh/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpresponse.rb:163:in `setup_header'
/home/ramesh/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpresponse.rb:101:in `send_response'
/home/ramesh/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:86:in `run'
/home/ramesh/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:183:in `block in start_thread'
```

This is the actual URL

> http://0.0.0.0:3000/list/#/items/offered/list/80-21614629999999,13-0468673/15/0?Filters={}

I am totally puzzled because the same works fine in my production environment.

Also If i remove the `?Filters={}` query string part from the url, it works fine in the dev environment.

I don't understand why this throws an error when using `?Filters={}` in dev env. can someone clarify this?

Answer (score 0):

{} should be escaped, and the following url is valid:

http://0.0.0.0:3000/list/#/items/offered/list/80-21614629999999,13-0468673/15/0?Filters=%7B%7D

UPDATE:

no, check https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986

```
fragment    = *( pchar / "/" / "?" )
pchar         = unreserved / pct-encoded / sub-delims / ":" / "@"
unreserved    = ALPHA / DIGIT / "-" / "." / "_" / "~"
sub-delims    = "!" / "$" / "&" / "'" / "(" / ")"
                / "*" / "+" / "," / ";" / "="
```

Comment: yeah i suspect that. but this is in the hash part of the url (not exactly a  query string).. so it should work

Comment: if so, it should be a bug of rails